# Use of undeclared identifier: Xcode, C code

Tags: xcode, undeclared-identifier

I'm getting an error "Use of undeclared identifier "BUFFER_LENGTH"". I've added the header in which "BUFFER_LENGTH" has been declared. I've shown the project structure below:

```
Project
 |_ main.c
 |_ application
    |_ main_functionality.c
 |_ headers
    |_ socket.h
```

**main.c**

```
#include "application/main_functionality.c"    
int main(int args, char *argv[]) {
       my_main(argc, argv);
       return 0;
    }
```

**main_functionality.c**

```
#include "../headers/socket.h"

unsigned char inputBuffer [BUFFER_LENGTH];  <-- ERROR!!!

int my_main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
\\ code
return 0;
}
```

**socket.h**

```
#if defined __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 256

#if defined __cpluscplus
}
#endif
```

socket.h contains the value for BUFFER_LENGTH and I've included the filename in main_functionality.c. I still get "Use of undeclared identifier" error.

Comment: In Xcode, look at main.c, click on the menu button in the top left corner (the one with 4 squares in it) and select "Preprocess" - look at the output to see if you're actually including what you think you're including.

Comment: A couple of other points: (i) you probably don't want to use `socket.h` as a user header name (it's a fairly common system header) and (ii) you don't need to bother with relative paths in your includes - just use the header name, add all relevant user headers and source files to your Xcode project, and let Xcode take care of the rest.

Comment: @PaulR : Thanks for the above suggestions. I removed the relative path to headers. Tried "headers/socket.h" and also "socket.h". But in both cases it complains file not found. And next thing is regarding the pre-processed output. I don't see any entry just above the line unsigned char inputBuffer [BUFFER_LENGTH]. For all other things I see the header file first and in next line the variable/function. So I'm guessing my header isn't included successfully? I'm a C/Linux person. Not sure how to build this in Xcode.

Comment: When you remove the relative paths you also need to add the files to your Xcode project - that way Xcode knows how to find them (`File` => `Add Files to ...`). You can also get rid of the include for `main_functionality.c` completely.

Comment: @PaulR : The files are added to the project. I can see the files and folder in project navigator. Is that enough assurance to say that I've added files successfully? Still I get file not found error if I remove relative paths.

Comment: After some research I figured out that I've to add header paths in build settings under user header search paths. After doing that I can just give the header names and it does not complain saying file not found. But the error of undeclared identifier is still as it is... And now I cannot see any output when I click on the preprocess button (4 squares)..

Comment: You really shouldn't have to add any additional header paths in the project settings if the headers are in the project, but without seeing how you've got the project configured it's hard to know what's going on.